# Configparser.py KeyError (Python/Flask)

Tags: python, flask

I am working on an app and I am getting this configparser.py error on my pythonanywhere deployment, however the app runs fine locally. I am not sure why this error is coming up.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/usr/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 845, in items
>       d.update(self._sections[section]) KeyError: 'cassBot'

Comment: Used blockquotes instead of formatting the error

Answer (score 0):

Treating "" as empty values was a bug in configparser pre 3.2 (it made it impossible to store "" as a value).

> In your case I advise u to changed bypass the bug like this:

- open /usr/lib/python3.7/configparser.py and edit lines 846,847,848

From :

```
except KeyError:
    if section != self.default_section:
        raise NoSectionError(section)
```

To :

```
except:
    pass
```

Comment: I never explicitly created a config file, is there a default location that i need to tell python to look for it?

Comment: I made a mistake , cz ur error is caused by a bug, that why I edited my answer

Comment: Thanks, but I have no idea where the error is pointing to. How do I find what instance of 'cassBot' it is referring to? Could it be related to wsgi?

Comment: try editing the file i mentioned in my answer I'm sure it gonna work in ur case

Comment: could it be something else, I dont have access to sudo on the server

Comment: It seems very unlikely to me that a bug that was fixed in `configparser` 3.2 (released in 2011 to match up with the built-in `configparser` module in Python 3.2) would exist in Python 3.7 (released this year).